# How to add where inside aggregate function in laravel?

Tags: laravel, function, aggregate

How can I add "where" inside this code?

```
$loans = LoanApplication::with('loanInterests')
        ->with(['loanPayments' => function($query) {
                $query->sum('amount_paid');
        }])->get();
```

i'd like to say "with `'loanPayments'`, sum `'amount_paid'` where `'type'` is `'payment'`.

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the function, `$query` is a normal query builder. I think this is what you want:

```
$loans = LoanApplication::with('loanInterests')
        ->with(['loanPayments' => function($query) {
                $query->sum('amount_paid');
                $query->where('type', 'payment');
        }])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `->where('type', 'payment')`
2. Select the `foreign_key` out, and group by `foreign_key`

```php
$loans = LoanApplication::with('loanInterests')
        ->with(['loanPayments' => function($query) {
                $query->where('type', 'payment')
                      ->select(DB::raw('SUM(amount_paid) AS sum_amount_paid'), 'loan_application_id')
                      ->groupBy('loan_application_id');
        }])->get();
```